# Terms of Policy and Privacy Policy for application release?

Tags: release, privacy, policy

I want to release my application in play store and app store.
But, That store require **PrivacyPolicyUrI** But I don't use signup system

And most application has terms of policy in their signup view
it is essential?
So...

1. PrivacyPolicy is required for non-signup application, too?
2. Terms of policy is required even if I'm just developer not company?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a Privacy Policy is required even for apps that do not require sign-up. However, a sign-up screen is good as you can use the clickwrap method of getting active constent from users to accept your Privacy Policy.

The requirement of a Privacy Policy is due to sensitive permissions you app may ask.

You can find the list of those permissions here: https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/personal-sensitive/

Even if you don’t need and ask those permissions, make sure you know what third parties you use in the app that might trigger this requirement (eg. [AdMob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42443983/6852845)).

You’ll need to add the URL to the Privacy Policy URL at Store Listing section. The link must be publicly accessible. Google will not host it for you.

[image]

A Terms of Service is not required, but it’s useful to add rules regarding user-generated content, unacceptable behaviour and so on. [For example](https://termsfeed.com/blog/terms-conditions-mobile-apps/#Clauses_for_Terms_Conditions_for_apps), it’s useful to add intellectual property clauses, ownership over your content and licenses over user-generated content clauses.